# How to get attribute value inside li tag?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, for-loop

I am using angular 6 application where i am passing data through attribute,

First i have given `[attr.parent_id]` in ul tag like,

```
<ul class="list-unstyled" id="1" [attr.parent_id]="123"></ul>
```

For which i have used, `console.log(target.getAttribute('parent_id'));`

And the result displays `123`.

Like same thing i need to get a index number from `li` tag like of the same `ul`,

```
<ul class="list-unstyled" id="1" [attr.parent_id]="123">
      <li class="media p-2 column" *ngFor="let item of items;let i = index;" [attr.child_id]="i"></li>
</ul>
```

Here i have given `[attr.child_id]` to retrieve the index position and i have used `console.log(target.getAttribute('child_id'));`.

This console of getting `child_id` displays the value as **null**.

The ul tag gives me the value of attribute but li tag is returning null as result.

The **StackBlitz** link was https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oaghq3

Kindly help me to set and get the attribute to li tag and to retrieve data.

Comment: The `I` in `childId` is uppercase. Could that be a problem?

Comment: @LucaKiebel, No it is also child_id only wrongly entered in question, now changed.

Comment: @user184994, Sorry... For parent id everywhere name is parent_id only and for child id everywhere name is child_id only.

Comment: I am not able to replicate it https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dtayyw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @brk, I need to get both attribute values at a time.. How will you get the ul attribute value in the link you provided??

Comment: @brk, I will not get anything on click.. I will get both parent and child values on ngOnInit itself..

Comment: @ManiRaj Are you able to create a StackBlitz to demonstrate what you want to achieve please?

Comment: @user184994, Stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oaghq3

Comment: Seems to work https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cejj9t?file=src/app/app.component.ts. I had to use `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit` so that the elements are rendered

Comment: @user184994, The parent_id value will be one always but the list will be many, how to get index of each list without using children[1]?

Comment: Well, children is a node list, so you could iterate through the array with a for loop

Comment: @user184994, I have used    
 ```let child = element.children;
    for(let i=0; i < child.length; i++) {
       console.log(child.getAttribute("child_id"))
    }``` but it is showing error as Property 'getAttribute' does not exist on type 'HTMLCollection'.

Comment: You probably want `child[i].getAttribute` otherwise you're referencing the entire list of children, or you can do as suggested below by @JotaToledo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the elements by using the `ViewChildren` decorator as showcased in this [blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lfyx8n)

```
<ul class="list-unstyled" id="list" [attr.parent_id]="123">
    <li #li class="media p-2 column" *ngFor="let item of items;let i = index;" [attr.child_id]="i"> {{item.name}} </li>
</ul>

@ViewChildren("li") listElements: QueryList<ElementRef<HTMLLIElement>>;

private printElements() {
    const elements = this.listElements.toArray();
    elements.forEach(element => {
      const isLiElemenet = element.nativeElement instanceof HTMLLIElement;
      const child_id = element.nativeElement.getAttribute('child_id');
      console.log({ isLiElemenet, child_id });
    })
  }
```